# How to load partials on a multiple page form in Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to convert Railscast #217. I want to change a multi-partial form so that it loads the partials using AJAX.
I have a website where users can register.  I have a registration form which consists of three partials (_step1.html.erb thru _step3.html.erb).

**user.rb** contains an array of the partial names and methods to go to the next and previous steps:

```
def current_step
  @current_step || steps.first
end

def steps
  %w[step1 step2 step3]
end

def next_step
  self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step) + 1]
end

def previous_step
  self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step) - 1]
end

def first_step?
  current_step == steps.first
end

def last_step?
  current_step == steps.last
end
```

The **new** action is initiated to this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  session[:user_step] = nil
end
```

The **create** action is what moves you between the next step and the previous step:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      @user.current_step = session[:user_step]
      if params[:prev_button]
        @user.previous_step
      elsif @user.last_step?
        @user.save
      else
        @user.next_step
      end
      session[:user_step] = @user.current_step
    end
  end
end
```

The **new.html.erb** files renders the following partial when one clicks 'Next' on the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div id="partial">
  <%= render @user.current_step, :f => f %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Previous", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "prev_button"   %>
<%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "next_button" %>
```

My **create.js.erb** looks like this.

```
$("#partial").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @user.current_step) %>");
```

I think what I'm getting hung up in is maybe when the create vs the new action get called?  When I'm on route **users/new** I fill out the form and click 'Next'.  Then when I'm on partial step 2 and click 'Next' I move onto partial 3.  I can move back to partial 2 but when I try to hit previous on partial 2 nothing happens.  I don't get sent back to partial 1.  Now whatever partial I'm on the route still says **users/new** but I know the **create**  action is getting called because I can go between partials 2 and 3 just not back to partial 1.  Now partial 2 and 3 have only text in them, but partial 1 looks like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :first_name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'required' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :last_name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'required' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

I think I see the problem. When I load partials 2 and 3 I'm only rendering text.  But in partial 1 I need to render <%= and %>. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

What does what you have actually do?

I do see that you're setting current_step, then right after that calling next_step, which sets current_step again. You then call next_step yet again in your js.erb file which means current_step is changed 3 times with each pass.

So current_step is likely well beyond your 3 steps at the point you're seeing issues.

Comment: what I have does nothing. When I click 'Next' nothing happens (this is with `remote: true` added to `form_for`).  I don't know how exactly to load a partial, with the next step of my array, via AJAX?

Comment: It could be any number of things that are hard to debug without seeing all your code. I'd still clean up the things I mentioned for sure. But backing up, does that page update if you do this instead: $("#partial").html("test") ?

Comment: Yes, this works.  It seems like my .js.erb file is not seeing my `@user` instance variable.

Comment: Did you clean up all the stuff I suggested? I bet your next_step value has exceeded your 3 steps considering it gets incremented 3 times in each step as I pointed out.

Comment: ok, that's supposed to be `render @user.current_step` in the js.erb file.  Which is not working either.

Comment: OK, then looking further, the only place @current_step is set is in def current_step so it's always going to result in steps.first. Therefore next_step will always result in the second step.